# VTIME and VMIN don't seem to change the blocking behaviour of the posix read() call

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, posix, uart

I am trying to understand how `VMIN` and `VTIME` works to control the blocking behaviour of the `read()` posix call.

In my example, I have set `VTIME` to 10 (and have tried other combinations too) which should block the read for 1 second until it's unblocked, yes? That's my understanding but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I opened minimum on my host, and I see `read()` would only unblock as soon as I hit `enter` in minicom as opposed to waiting for 1 second to unblock.

Is my understanding incorrect? If not so, what could be wrong?

```
int Serial_Open(char *port)
{
    int serial_port = open(port, O_RDWR);
    struct termios tty;

    // Read in existing settings, and handle any error
    if(tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) 
    {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // Clear parity bit, disabling parity (most common)
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // Clear stop field, only one stop bit used in communication (most common)
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; // Clear all bits that set the data size 
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 bits per byte (most common)
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable RTS/CTS hardware flow control (most common)
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines (CLOCAL = 1)

    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // Disable echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; // Disable erasure
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; // Disable new-line echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG; // Disable interpretation of INTR, QUIT and SUSP
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Turn off s/w flow ctrl
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL); // Disable any special handling of received bytes

    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // Prevent special interpretation of output bytes (e.g. newline chars)
    tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR; // Prevent conversion of newline to carriage return/line feed

    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;    // Wait for up to 1s, returning as soon as any data is received.
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

    cfsetspeed(&tty, B115200);

    if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) 
    {
        printf("Error tcsetattr %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
  return serial_port;
}

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[100];
  int ret;

  int fd = Serial_Open("/dev/ttyUSB4");
  
  while(1)
  {
        ret = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (ret <= 0)
        {
           printf ("No data or error\n");
        }
        else
        {
           printf ("Rxd data: %s\n", buffer);
        }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: *"...which should block the read for 1 second until it's unblocked, yes? That's my understanding ..."* -- No. Your understanding is incorrect.  Read the **man** page for termios.  BTW your code does not compile as posted: **Serial_Open()** is declared a void routine.  **read()** does not return a string, so your **printf()** can display garbage (as well as stale data).

Comment: I read this -> https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/operating-systems/linux/linux-serial-ports-using-c-cpp/#vmin-and-vtime-c_cc - it says `VMIN=0, VTIME>0` is a blocking read of ANY number of chars with a timeout given by whatever's `VTIME` is set to, which in my case is 1s. basically `read()` blocks until either any amount of data is available or the timeout occurs. So if the timeout is 1s, and no data has been received, shouldn't it unblock after?

Comment: One more time: read the **man** page for termios.  Don't quote or rely on some unknown who tries to describe in fewer words the **man** page.  And your code is still broken even after the quick fix.

Comment: "The timer is started when read(2) is called. read(2) returns either when at least one byte of data is available, or when the timer expires. ". This still sounds the familiar to me. Am I missing something else too?

Comment: You wrote that you think setting `VTIME` to 10 should "block the read for 1 second until it's unblocked".  Even if we combine this with the information drawn from you code that you are also setting `VMIN` to zero and disabling canonical mode, it sounds incorrect.  That configuration should cause `read()` to block *up to* one second, *provided that* no data have yet been read.  There may be less than one second of blocking, and the read does not necessarily block at all.  Perhaps that is the understanding you were trying to convey, but it did not come across that way to me.

Comment: "read() to block up to one second, provided that no data have yet been read" that's what I'm getting at, yes. But the main concern is that doesn't seem to be case when I run

Comment: Blocking simply means that the syscall might cause the caller to be suspended. For VMIN=0 and VTIME=10, noncanoncal **read()** will return when ***either*** any data is available ***or*** 10 deciseconds have expired.  The caller is only suspended for the full VTIME if and only if there is no data available.  This is *not* a "timed" read that fetches as much data as possible for a given time interval.

Comment: yes, but `read()` doesn't seem to return at all in my case until I hit enter in minicom.

Comment: I've executed your code (with proper corrections).  It performs as expected; any character sent to the program from the remote terminal causes the **read()** to return immediately (instead of timing out).  I increased VTIME to 100 to properly differentiate delay.

Comment: so you can observe with vmin=0, vtime=100, `read` only returns after 10s given no data was inputted?

Comment: Yes.  That is how it is supposed to work.  That is how I see it work.

Comment: Interesting. Wondering what's causing it to not work on my end. read remains blocked until I hit enter

Comment: Check the USB Serial device.  In most C environments, output is line buffered; it is possible/likely that your USB Serial device is buffering the data internally until Enter is pressed.  In standard C, you either need to make `stdout` unbuffered or add `fflush(stdout)` to ensure the data is actually written and not buffered by the C library.  In POSIX C, `write()` does not buffer, but may return a short count.  In Arduino, you may need to use `Serial.flush()` or equivalent, depending on the microcontroller core used (AVR, ARM, Teensy, STM, etc.).

Comment: where are you adding `fflush(stdout)`? also do you see why read() gets unblocked only after pressing enter?

Comment: *"read remains blocked until I hit enter"* -- You're (inaccurately) inferring a cause-effect relationship without evidence.  *"also do you see why read() gets unblocked only after pressing enter?"* -- You have provided no evidence that the later causes the former.  How do you know that your sender in not is `line mode`, i.e. transmit (of the whole line) only occurs after `Enter` is pressed?  Seems like you're making hasty conclusions with just one experiment.  Did you try to send a single character with `echo -n A >/dev/ttyXXX` ?  And exactly what is your test setup?

Comment: *"read remains blocked until I hit enter"* -- If **read()** returns only after a newline has been received, then the simplest explanation is that you are not executing the program you have posted.  The code that you have posted configures the serial terminal to noncanonical (aka raw) mode, which *ignores* line termination characters.  Termios has be be in canonical mode in order to respond to line termination characters (and VMIN & VTIME are not used).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot duplicate the claimed behaviour, using the following example program:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0

#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int             tty_fd = -1;
static struct termios  tty_old;

static void  tty_close(void)
{
    if (tty_fd == -1)
        return;

    tcsetattr(tty_fd, TCSAFLUSH, &tty_old);

    if (tty_fd != STDIN_FILENO  &&
        tty_fd != STDOUT_FILENO &&
        tty_fd != STDERR_FILENO)
        close(tty_fd);

    tty_fd = -1;
}

static int  tty_open(const char *ttypath)
{
    struct termios  tty_new;
    int             fd;

    if (tty_fd != -1)
        tty_close();

    if (!ttypath || !*ttypath)
        return errno = ENOENT;

    do {
        fd = open(ttypath, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_CLOEXEC);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno;

    if (!isatty(fd)) {
        close(fd);
        return errno = ENOTTY;
    }

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty_old) == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(fd);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    tty_new = tty_old;

    /* No input processing.  No input flow control.  Ignore parity.  Break reads as '\0'. */
    tty_new.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | INPCK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IUCLC | IXON | IXANY | IXOFF);
    tty_new.c_iflag |= IGNPAR;

    /* No output processing. */
    // tty_new.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST | OLCUC | ONLCR | OCRNL | ONOCR | ONLRET);
    tty_new.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* 8 data bits, No parity, 1 stop bit, no hardware flow control, ignore modem control lines. */
    tty_new.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB | CSTOPB | CRTSCTS);
    tty_new.c_cflag |= CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;

    /* Raw mode, no signals, no echo. */
    tty_new.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | ECHO | IEXTEN);

    /* VMIN=0, VTIME=10 */
    tty_new.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tty_new.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty_new) == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(fd);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    /* Some of the above settings may not have been applied.
       We could check, but really, we don't care that much. */
    tty_fd = fd;

    return 0;
}

#ifndef  TTY_BUFSIZ
#define  TTY_BUFSIZ  128
#endif

static unsigned char           tty_buf[TTY_BUFSIZ];
static volatile unsigned char *tty_head = tty_buf;
static volatile unsigned char *tty_tail = tty_buf;

#define  TTY_NONE  -1
#define  TTY_EOF   -2
#define  TTY_ERROR -3

static int tty_getc_read(void)
{
    tty_head = tty_tail = tty_buf;
    if (tty_fd == -1)
        return TTY_EOF;

    ssize_t  n = read(tty_fd, tty_buf, sizeof tty_buf);
    if (n > 0) {
        tty_tail = tty_buf + n;
        return *(tty_head++);
    } else
    if (n == 0) {
        return TTY_NONE;
    } else
    if (n != -1 || (errno != EINTR && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)) {
        return TTY_ERROR;
    } else {
        return TTY_NONE;
    }
}

static inline int tty_getc(void)
{
    if (tty_tail > tty_head)
        return *(tty_head++);
    else
        return tty_getc_read();
}


static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    if (!done)
        done = (signum > 0) ? signum : -1;
}

static int install_done(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *cmd = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", cmd);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s TTY-DEVICE\n", cmd);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This reads in raw mode from the TTY device.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (install_done(SIGINT) || install_done(SIGTERM) ||
        install_done(SIGHUP) || install_done(SIGQUIT)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (tty_open(argv[1])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot open TTY: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Press CTRL+C to exit.\r\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    int  last_none = 0;

    while (!done) {
        int  ch = tty_getc();

        if (ch == TTY_NONE) {
            printf(".");
            fflush(stdout);
            last_none = 1;
            continue;
        } else
        if (last_none) {
            printf("\r\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            last_none = 0;
        }

        if (ch == TTY_EOF) {
            printf("End-of-input received.\r\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            break;
        } else
        if (ch == TTY_ERROR) {
            printf("Read error occurred.\r\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            break;
        } else
        if (ch == 3) {
            printf("Received 0x03 = \\003, assuming Ctrl+C. Exiting.\r\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            break;
        } else {
            if (ch >= 32 && ch <= 126)
                printf("Received 0x%02x = \\%03o = %3d = '%c'\r\n", (unsigned int)ch, (unsigned int)ch, ch, ch);
            else
                printf("Received 0x%02x = \\%03o = %3d\r\n", (unsigned int)ch, (unsigned int)ch, ch);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    if (last_none) {
        printf("\r\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    tty_close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Specify the serial or terminal or pseudoterminal device path on the command line; use `$(tty)` for the current terminal/pseudoterminal.

Comparing OP's, `Serial_Open()` and my `tty_open()`, I do believe the terminal settings are essentially the same (and moreover, any differences there are do not explain the difference in behaviour).

You can compile the above example (example.c) as e.g. `gcc -Wall -O2 example.c -o example` and then run it via `./example $(tty)` to read input from the same terminal window.

This leads me to believe the problem is in the other end: that whatever OP uses to generate the data read by this end, is line-buffered.